# Amazon EC2 ssh from public instance to private instance in vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am new to Amazon EC2, and I want to access to private instance using ssh utility from public instance.

Here is my settings.

**instance list in the vpc**
[image: instance list in the vpc]

**private instance's information**
[image: private instance's information]

**private instance's inbound rule of security group**
[image: private instance's inbound rule of security group]

**ssh connection timedout**
[image: ssh failed]

even I can't ping to private instance. Why could not access to private instance?

**EDIT: Added routing table information**
[image]

[image]

by the way, i am sorry I don't know how to change language in console view.

Edit again : connecting with pem file, to private ip of private instance from public instance using ssh.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the route table for the private subnet. Your route table in the private subnet should have Desination (VPC CIDR) Target (local) and a NAT Gateway Destination (0.0.0.0/0) and Target (nat-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx). If you want to be able to ping your instances, you will need to add "All ICMP - IPv4" to the security group Inbound Rules.

Comment: @John Hanley, Thank you for answering my question, I edited my post, the last image seems to have 0.0.0.0/0, and nat-XXX. And I can't ping also after adding "ALL ICMP IPv4" to my private instance's security group inbound. Isn't it right to ping to private instane's elastic IP address?

Comment: If they are in the same VPC you should be able to SSH into the private instance. Try modifying the incoming security rule for the private instance to allow SSH from the security group id that the public instance belongs to which should start with "sg-", similar to how you allowed that MYSQL access

Comment: @Nagulb Ihab The 3rd picture is what you're talking about i guess..

Comment: This tutorial might help https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/

Comment: @strongjz thank you for your support, but this case was closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the Private IP address** (starting with `10.` -- from your pictures, it is probably `10.0.1.101`) to connect from the public instance to the private instance -- it appears that you are trying to connect to a Public IP address, which will not work.

Ping is disabled by default unless you allow it in your Security Group, so **do not use Ping to diagnose network configurations**.

If your **SSH** command is hanging, this is an indication that there is no network connectivity. The most common cause is the Security Group. Temporarily open all traffic (`0.0.0.0/0`) for port 22 in the Security Group and test whether this works. (If the instance is in a private subnet, it cannot be reached from outside the VPC anyway!)

There is no need to use a **NAT Gateway** unless your private instance requires access to the Internet.

It appears that you are attempting to use the SSH command with a .PPK file, which is incorrect -- **PPK files are only used for PuTTY**. For the SSH command, use the PEM file. If you do not wish to store the key on the public (web) instance, then use Pageant with PuTTY and enable agent forwarding. See: [How To SSH Hop With Key Forwarding from Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/125364/how-to-ssh-hop-with-key-forwarding-from-windows/)

Other tips:

- Make sure both instances are in the **same VPC**
- Your Private Security Group is permitting access from `122.40.73.88/32`, which is a Public IP address. This will not work, since the instance is in a private subnet.

Comment: Hi John Rotenstein, thank you for answering my question. I did what you asked in my vpc. The vpc has two instances - private one, and the other is public. I updated my post with edit-contents. thanks

Comment: You should **NOT** have an Elastic IP address on a private instance. You should **connect to the private instance with the private IP address** (10.0.1.101).

Comment: Thank you. I re-tried everything from the start, and it worked. Maybe the cause was elastic IP you said. Problem solved. Sincerely thank you.